# From shell script can we invoke function from here document

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I would like to write a shell script that should call a function from here document as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
funexit 
funexit  ()
{
  exit 1
}

cat <<:EOD:
funexit 
:EOD:
```

Please suggest a good solution to me!

Answer (score 6):

If I understood you correctly, then you need like this,

```
funexit()
{
  echo "calling funexit"
  exit 1
}

cat <<:EOD:
$(funexit)
:EOD:
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
funexit()        # Declare function 
{
  echo $1        # echo parameter
  cat            # cat STDIN
  exit 1         # exit (badly)
}

funexit 3 <<EOD  # call function with parameter 3
hello            # pass "hello" to its STDIN
EOD
```

Output:

```
./go
3
hello
~: echo $?       # Check exit status is 1
1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce @Mark. I want function need to get called under here document..