# Function calls in Here Document for unix shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh

I'm working on a shell script to move some files around. This script needs to be able to operate on files either on a local machine or on a remote server depending on the arguments passed in. I have managed to put together a simple function that does what I want. What I can't seem to figure out is how to use that function in a Here document so it can be executed on the remote server. I found a similar question here: [From shell script can we invoke function from here document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953160/from-shell-script-can-we-invoke-function-from-here-document) but the given answers don't work for me.

Here is what I have come up with so far:

**myscript.sh**

```
REMOTE_HOST=myserver
JETTY_BASE=/opt/web/jetty

doMove()
{
    echo "$JETTY_BASE/webapps/eyerep-data/$1"       
    sudo touch $JETTY_BASE/webapps/eyerep-data/$1/myfile
    ls $JETTY_BASE/webapps/eyerep-data/$1;
}

moveRemote()
{
    echo "attempting move with here doc"    
    ssh -t $REMOTE_HOST "/bin/bash <<EOF
$(doMove $1) 
EOF"
    
}

moveFiles()
{   
        case "$1" in
      # remote deploy
      remote)
        moveRemote $2
        ;;
      # local deploy
      local)
        doMove $2
        ;;
      *)
        echo "Usage: myscript.sh {local|remote}"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
    
}
```

If I run the above with

> ./myscript.sh remote dev

I get an output like:

```
attempting move with here doc
/bin/bash: line 1: /opt/web/jetty/webapps/eyerep-data/: Is a directory
/bin/bash: line 2: dev: command not found
/bin/bash: line 3: eyerep-data-dev.xml: command not found
/bin/bash: line 4: eyerep-data-local.xml: command not found
/bin/bash: line 5: local: can only be used in a function
```

Looking at the output, it looks like it is trying to pass the output from the 'echo' and 'ls' calls to /bin/bash as commands instead of printing them to the console. While this is a contrived example, I would like to be able to have logging statements inside my function that print to stdout. What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: `$(doMove $1)` produces the results of executing the commands in the body of the function; it does not produce a list of those commands for the remote shell to execute.

Comment: So what would be the correct syntax to use then?

Comment: There isn't one, in general. `doMove` is defined locally, not remotely, so you can't call it on the remote host.

Comment: A usage statement is not an error message.  You should either emit an error message and exit 1, or you should emit a usage statement and exit 0.  If you choose to write an error message, print it to stderr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

REMOTE_HOST=myserver
JETTY_BASE=/opt/web/jetty

generateMoveCommands() {
    __="echo ${JETTY_BASE@Q}/webapps/eyerep-data/${1@Q}
sudo touch ${JETTY_BASE@Q}/webapps/eyerep-data/${1@Q}/myfile
ls ${JETTY_BASE@Q}/webapps/eyerep-data/${1@Q}"
}

moveLocal() {
    generateMoveCommands "$1"
    eval "$__"
}

moveRemote() {
    echo "Attempting move with here doc"
    generateMoveCommands "$1"
    ssh -t "$REMOTE_HOST" "$__"
}

showUsage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 {local|remote} file"
    exit 1
}

main() {
    case $1 in
    # remote deploy
    remote)
        [[ $2 ]] || showUsage
        moveRemote "$2"
        ;;
    # local deploy
    local)
        [[ $2 ]] || showUsage
        moveLocal "$2"
        ;;
    *)
        showUsage
        ;;
    esac
}

main "$@"
```

The form `${param@Q}` expands value to a quoted version which allows to be safely re-evaluated as an argument.  It's a Bash feature that became available starting 4.4.

Alternative solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

REMOTE_HOST=myserver
JETTY_BASE=/opt/web/jetty

doMove() {
    local jetty_base=$1 file=$2
    echo "${jetty_base}/webapps/eyerep-data/${file}"
    sudo touch "${jetty_base}/webapps/eyerep-data/${file}/myfile"
    ls "${jetty_base}/webapps/eyerep-data/${file}"
}

moveRemote() {
    echo "Attempting move with here doc"
    ssh -t "$REMOTE_HOST" "$(declare -fp doMove)"$'\n'"doMove ${JETTY_BASE@Q} ${1@Q}"
}

showUsage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 {local|remote} file"
    exit 1
}

main() {
    case $1 in
    # remote deploy
    remote)
        [[ $2 ]] || showUsage
        moveRemote "$2"
        ;;
    # local deploy
    local)
        [[ $2 ]] || showUsage
        doMove "$JETTY_BASE" "$2"
        ;;
    *)
        showUsage
        ;;
    esac
}

main "$@"
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the '__' in generateMoveCommands? Is that special syntax or could it be replaced by a normal variable name?

Comment: it's like any other variable. I use it as a temporary global and common iterator.

Comment: No luck so far. If I try to run that script I end up with 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified' when it tries to make a sudo call.

Comment: Try changing `printf '%s\n' "$__" | ssh -t "$REMOTE_HOST" /bin/bash` to `ssh -t "$REMOTE_HOST" /bin/bash -c "$__"`.

Comment: Something about that command is not right. I get errors like 'usage: sudo [-D level] -h | -K | -k | -V' which seems to indicate that it is not executing a valid sudo command. The same thing happens if I just try to run a single line i.e.                 ssh myhost /bin/bash -c 'sudo cp ~/eyerep-files/start.ini ~/dev/start_b.ini'

Comment: @pbuchheit My mistake. I based it on your original command. You shouldn't specify `/bin/bash` nor `-c`. Just specify the command right away, so: `ssh -t "$REMOTE_HOST" "$__"`. This solution however requires that `/bin/sh` is `bash`, or that you're only allowed to use POSIX compatible commands in there.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Do you know if it is possible to go the other direction? In other words, is it possible to start with a block of code and wrap it into a string for the remote call rather than starting with a string and calling eval for local?

Comment: You can send the function as a string and along with it the value of the filename and the "base dir", but that's almost the same as sending the commands quoted.

Comment: How would I do that? The problem is that the actual move function is considerably more complex than the example I used here. It will be much easier to maintain if I start with a function and wrap it.

Comment: Take a look at the alternate version I just added.

Comment: That solution was enough to solve the original problem. I'm still having some other issues, but they go beyond the scope of the original question, so I created a new one here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70614226/forcing-string-replacement-in-declared-function-of-shell-script . Thanks for all the help working through this.